# XPM - The input data was invalid: InitialPublicationDate must not be null

Tags: experience-manager, 2011-sp1

In Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2, when trying to update the content of an RTF field, I get the following message back.  I suspect this is an issue with the OData configuration, but I am not able to find what I've missed.

[image]

> The input data was invalid: InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null., InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null., InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null.

---

The OData log in debug mode shows the following, and I can see the information considered null does exist in the input string:

> 2015-05-18 08:22:37,338 DEBUG AbstractWritableEntryService - Updating entity from webservice endpoint.
>   2015-05-18 08:22:37,338 DEBUG EntityParser - Parsing input string=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">  
<category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Component" />  
<title />  
<author>    <name />  </author>  
<updated>2015-05-18T12:22:37.2952812Z</updated>
<id>http://localhost:71/odata.svc/Components(ItemId=3208,PublicationId=40)</id>
<content type="application/xml">    
<m:properties>      
<d:Author>T2011GURUV3\Administrator</d:Author>      
<d:CreationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-02-06T13:35:48.01Z</d:CreationDate>      
<d:InitialPublishDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-18T12:17:04.21Z</d:InitialPublishDate>      
<d:ItemId m:type="Edm.Int32">3208</d:ItemId>      
<d:LastPublishDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-18T12:22:37.2786797Z</d:LastPublishDate>      
<d:MajorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:MajorVersion>      
<d:MinorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:MinorVersion>      
<d:ModificationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-18T12:22:34.923Z</d:ModificationDate>      
<d:Multimedia m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Multimedia>      
<d:OwningPublication m:type="Edm.Int32">37</d:OwningPublication>      
<d:PublicationId m:type="Edm.Int32">40</d:PublicationId>      
<d:SchemaId m:type="Edm.Int32">3049</d:SchemaId>      
<d:Title>Article A feb 6</d:Title>    
</m:properties>  
</content>
</entry> with mediaType=application/atom+xml.
```

> 2015-05-18 08:22:37,344 DEBUG ItemMetaParser - Parsed ItemMeta{itemId=3208, publicationId=40, majorVersion=3, minorVersion=1, owningPublication=37, itemType=16, itemSelector='component', title='Article A feb 6', creationDate='null', initialPublishDate='null', lastPublishDate='null', trustee='T2011GURUV3\Administrator', modificationDate='null', customMetaValues='[]' from input string.
>   2015-05-18 08:22:37,345 ERROR ODataWebserviceHandler - Validation exception while updating an entity.
>   com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataValidationException: The input data was invalid: InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null., InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null., InitialPublicationDate must not be null., ModificationDate must not be null.
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.AbstractWritableEntryService.update(AbstractWritableEntryService.java:79) ~[cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.updateODataEntity(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:371) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleChangeSet(ODataBatchHandler.java:127) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleBatch(ODataBatchHandler.java:52) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleBatch(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:346) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
>   2015-05-18 08:22:37,346 ERROR ODataBatchHandler - Operation failed with status code 400, rolling back the transaction and generating error response.

---

The publication target has the OData url as http://localhost:71/odata.svc/
The website specified there is http://localhost:70
The publication properties have an extra "A" folder, could this be what's confusing OData here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your paramater

```
<d:ModificationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-18T12:22:34.923Z</d:ModificationDate>
```

you've indicated a type of

> Edm.DateTime

but in the content you are using

> Edm.DateTimeOffset

see http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/ for reference.

I seem to recall there was a defect with ODATA on this sometime back and I see you're using 2011-SP1

Comment: Is this related to this post... http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/how-to-modify-attribute-types-for-the-content-delivery-web-service/5659#5659